# Can my two linq lines of code be combined?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm not sure how to do this since I'm only familiar with the basic form or Linq.

Here are my two sets of code:

```
var qry = from x in CustomersChecks.CustomersChecksList
  where x.RoutingNumber == routingnumber &&
        x.BankAccountNumber == bankAccountNumber &&
    x.Branch > 0 &&
    x.AccountNumber > 0
    orderby x.Name
  select x;
```

```
var qry2 = qry.GroupBy(x => new { x.Branch, x.AccountNumber}).Select(x => x.First()).ToList();
```

Ultimately, I want to get my first query in order of Branch + Account Number distinctly.

Can they be combined or is what I have the only way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried simply chaining the two instead of doing a tolist and then doing the groupby?

Comment: Yes, they can be combined. Just replace `.ToList` with `.GroupBy...` etc. On a side note, I reccomend sticking with one syntax or the other, instead of mixing them.

Comment: ok let me try that ty

Comment: @mason Yeah, I'm not familiar enough with the second syntax. I found the code online and was trying to incorporate it in.

Comment: The other option is to add the group by into the query syntax of the first query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quick and dirty solution is just to add the `GroupBy` chain to the end of the first query.

```
var qry = (from x in CustomersChecks.CustomersChecksList
          where x.RoutingNumber == routingnumber &&
          x.BankAccountNumber == bankAccountNumber &&
          x.Branch > 0 &&
          x.AccountNumber > 0
          orderby x.Name
          select x).GroupBy(x => new { x.Branch, x.AccountNumber})
                   .Select(x => x.First())
                   .ToList();
```

Or do the following by incorrupating the group by into the exist query syntax

```
var qry = (from x in CustomersChecks.CustomersChecksList
          where x.RoutingNumber == routingnumber &&
          x.BankAccountNumber == bankAccountNumber &&
          x.Branch > 0 &&
          x.AccountNumber > 0
          orderby x.Name
          group x by new { x.Branch, x.AccountNumber} into grp
          select grp.First()).ToList();
```

Comment: Awesome! That is what I was looking for, something I would better understand. Tyvm!

Comment: @ErocM There was one issue with the second query that I just fixed.

Comment: That helps, I think I better understand how group works now. Tyvm!

Answer (score 2):

```
var qry = CustomersChecks.CustomersChecksList.Where(x =>
    x.RoutingNumber == routingnumber &&
    x.BankAccountNumber == bankAccountNumber &&
    x.Branch > 0 &&
    x.AccountNumber > 0).OrderBy(x => x.Name)
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.Branch, x.AccountNumber})
    .Select(x => x.First())
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Actually need the `OrderBy` before the `Groupby` as it will effect what `First` returns.